# How to get back local save character in Terraria?

Tags: terraria-mobile

I had a character that was on the cloud save page and when I clicked on it, it always asked if I wanted the local save one or the cloud save one (it was synced with my brother's iPad). Local save has my newer stuff. Then today I accidently clicked cloud save and now it doesn't ask me if I want the cloud or local save. I lost everything such as the True Excalibur and the Rainbow Rod, and am now stuck with palladium tools and shadow mail armor. Please help.(if it isn't possible then please tell me)

Answer (score 2):

Like GnomeSlice said in the comments, there is basically no way to do that on an iOS device as the Cloud Save file overwrote your Local File. Sorry!